# Is it possible to replace a class with routerLinkActive instead of just adding a class?

Tags: css, angular, angular2-directives, angular-router

I have an icon on a navigation bar which serves as a link to a `admin` route, I'd like this icon to change when I'm on that specific route, for this I can just replace the `mdi-settings-outline` class with `mdi-settings`, which will show a *filled* version of the same icon.

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a routerLink="/admin" routerLinkActive="mdi-settings" class="nav-link mdi mdi-settings-outline"></a>
</li>
```

However the regular `routerLinkActive` directive will only *add* the `mdi-settings` class to the link, which won't have the desired result. Can the routerLinkActive directive somehow *replace* the class instead of just adding it?

Comment: I thought the directive acted as an equivalent to `blah.classList.toggle('blah blah')` so `routerLinkActive="mdi-settings-outline mdi-settings"` would remove `mdi-settings-outline` if present and add `mdi-settings` if it's not.

Comment: @ChrisW. that actually sounds right as well and could work

Comment: @ChrisW. tried it, but didn't seem to work properly

Comment: Well dang, they should probably update the first sentence of [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#active-router-links) lol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `routerLinkActive` exports some properties that you can use in the template. You access the API by assigning the directive to a template variable. This is done by adding `#link="routerLinkActive"` where "link" is the name of the variable.

You can then use the properties of the directive, which are defined here in the API documentation.

https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive#properties

```html
<li class="nav-item">
    <a routerLink="/admin" 
       routerLinkActive="mdi-settings"
       #link="routerLinkActive"
       class="nav-link mdi"
       [class.mdi-settings-outline]="!link.isActive"
    ></a>
</li>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm... And looking at the code it actually makes a lot of sense, thank you very much

Comment: Is it `active` or `isActive`?

Comment: @ConnorsFan it is `isActive` actually

Comment: @ConnorsFan yup, you're right. I updated the answer. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Need to make the variable unique for each link

```
    <a mat-list-item
       [routerLinkActive]="['']"
       [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"
       #reportsLink="routerLinkActive"
       [ngClass]="reportsLink.isActive ? 'route-active': 'route-inactive'"
       [routerLink]="['/reports']"
       title="Reports">
    </a>
    <a mat-list-item
       [routerLinkActive]="['']"
       [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"
       #notificationsLink="routerLinkActive"
       [ngClass]="notificationsLink.isActive ? 'route-active': 'route-inactive'"
       [routerLink]="['/notifications']"
       title="Notifications">
    </a>
```